# toggle class div elements in react.js

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am newbie in Reactjs.

I am trying to make each different toggle div classes when click buttons.

```
import React from 'react';

class Home extends React.Component{
  
  state = { isActive: false }; 
  handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: !this.state.isActive });
  }; 

  render(){  
    const isActive = this.state.isActive; 

    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.handleToggle} className={isActive ? "btn1" : "btn-on1"}>Toggle class1</button>
        <div className={isActive ? "box1" : "box-active1"}>11</div>
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.handleToggle} className={isActive ? "btn2" : "btn-on2"}>Toggle class2</button>
        <div className={isActive ? "box2" : "box-active2"}>22</div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
  
export default Home;
```

The problem is when click button, both button toggle together at same time.
I want to make them each button toggle only itself.

How do I fix it ?

Comment: what do you mean "not working well."?

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing, what's not working well?

Comment: @Nithish  I want to make them each button toggle only itself.

Comment: If you have multiple things that need their own state then each thing needs its own state; a single state value is insufficient.

Comment: Oh, you're just toggling between two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could achieve this by changing the state from boolean so it can refer to a specific div:

```
state = { isActive: '' }; 
  handleToggle = (btn) => {
    this.setState({ isActive: btn });
  }; 

  render(){  
    const isActive = this.state.isActive; 

    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleToggle('button1')} className={isActive === 'button1' ? "btn1" : "btn-on1"}>Toggle class1</button>
        <div className={isActive === 'button1' ? "box1" : "box-active1"}>11</div>
        <br />
        <button onClick={() => this.handleToggle('button2')} className={isActive === 'button2' ? "btn2" : "btn-on2"}>Toggle class2</button>
        <div className={isActive === 'button2' ? "box2" : "box-active2"}>22</div>
      </>
    )
  }
```